# How to declare a TypeScript interface with variable number of properties?

Tags: typescript

This is a simple question, and I'm surprised that I can't find a clear answer to it anywhere. I'm making an API and I need to define an Interface that can have multiple (string) properties, but there's no set number of properties and no set names for them (but they all have to have string values). So all of the following objects would match the type:

```
{ slot: "ten" }

{ class: "Luxury", base: "never", city: "Timbuktu" }

{ slot: "ten", class: "Luxury" }
```

I've thought of the following.

```
interface MyInterface {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

But to me, this says that the objects can have *only one* property (of varying name), rather than that they can have multiple properties (of varying names).

What's the best way to do this? Note that I can't control what property names the code that calls my API will use. Callers can use whatever property names that they want.

Comment: As you defined it, an object of type `MyInterface` can have any number of properties whose names are strings and values are also strings. If you don't have a fixed list of property names, `MyInterface` seems to be what you need. On the other hand, by not having a clearly defined interface, your API works against TypeScript.

Comment: If you just want to define an object that can contain any number of strings as properties, just use [`Record<string, string>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)

Comment: Thanks @rickdenhaan. `Record<string, string>` seems to be exactly what I need. Please make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @axiac. That's a useful tidbit I'll file away. Although I think in my case it makes more sense to just use the existing Record than to create my own type. It's weird though that the bracket notation `[]` has **two** effects: it makes the property name variable, but it also makes the number of properties variable.

Comment: This syntax is called ["indexable type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

Comment: `Record<string, string>` evaluates to the equivalent of `MyInterface`.  If you accept one you should accept the other.

Comment: FYI, you can use the type `{[k: string]: string}` without giving it your own name like `MyInterface`.  And the `Record` type is just a type alias for a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which also uses a variant of bracket notation: `{[K in string]: string}`.  So you can write `Record<string, string>` if it looks better to you, but that bracket notation is still lurking around.

Comment: @jcalz I agree with both your comments (and I did know all this) and I would be happy to mark both rickdenhaan's and axiac's answers as correct (if either of them make them into answers).I just prefer `Record` because I think as a general principle, its better to use a type that's already in the language than to either make my own or to use anonymous types (which I hate).

Comment: You should always create your own custom types. Thats the whole point of typescript. Tjats how you make sure you with get the properties you are expecting. There is no such general principle. Always create your custom types from built in types. That’s why interference exists. that’s why typescript exists

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your `interface` might *look* like it only accepts a single property that has to be of type `string`, but that is actually the syntax used to define an interface with any number of properties that all share the same characteristics (strings as keys and strings as values). This is called an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) (credits to @axiac, I didn't know it had a name).

So there's nothing wrong with keeping the interface as it is:

```
interface MyInterface {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Typescript comes with a native utility type called [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) that boils down to the same thing but is more concise:

```
type MyInterface = Record<string, string>;
```

Functionally there's no difference between the two, which one you choose is up to your personal preference.

Answer (score -4):

You can’t and you should not do that. That’s the whole point of interfaces, to have a set of defined types. what you can do is: define all property names that you are expecting and mark them as optionals or refactor your models.
Try avoiding [key: string]: string;  it will compile now but will give you a headache later trying to fix those bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work because there are an infinite number of property names that I'm "expecting". Callers can use whatever property names they want.

Comment: then just use ‚any,. you are violating every single use case of interface. there is no point to use an interface in this case. you will gain nothing. it like saying you accept dollars in your store but pound, CAD and everything else is allowed. . you can just say: every currency is allowed. that’s the whole point of typescript. to define the type. (The biggest drawback of pure Javascript is that there are no types).

Comment: I don't agree with your reasoning. To use your metaphor, **NOT** every currency is allowed. Using an Interface (or `Record<string, string>`) does provide some type safety that `any` does not: It prevents callers from passing arrays, or strings, or numbers, or objects that have array or number property values.

Comment: does it prevent passing ““ (empty string) as a property name. ? There is no point on doing smth like this. this is the reason why you couldn’t find anything on the wen. What devs do is that they define optional properties. Then you can use an adaptor to map the data you receive. This is wrong in every direction. You can not do such s thing in a type safe language

Comment: @RexhinHoxha [String index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) are documented to be useful for "dictionary" objects, where you don't care about the key names but you do want the values to be of a known type.  Can you point to an authoritative source that corroborates the assertion that index signatures should always be avoided and are no better than `any`?  Or is it just your opinion?

Comment: what would you do to a property name like this? “;6),;46 漢語 / 汉语“. it is a valid string.

Comment: @M1X yeah, sounds like a valid property - tested it (wrapped in "" since yours are curved). What's the issue with it, besides not being very semantic?

Comment: I had a very real use case for this, where i needed to accept an object with an arbitrary number of objects containing a very specifically named field. This could have been done with an array of objects, but using a normalized type like { [typeName: string]: {[fieldName: string]: { handler: string } } } made it much easier to understand as it more closely matched the relationship of the contained objects